# Сохранение модифицированного JSON в файл

Tags: python, dict

Есть файл вида:

```
{"andrey": {"Secret": "124f2f2asdfsdfqwe23sdg", "uid": "31124235535"}}
{"anton: {"Secret": "124f422342f2asdfsdfqwe23sdg", "uid": " "}}
```

Где `uid` - переменная.

```
with open('project/users.txt', 'r+') as data_file:      
  for line in data_file:
    for k, v in json.loads(line).items():
      if v['Secret'] in Token:
        Name = (k[:])
        text = json.load(line)
        text(k[:]['uid'] = str(username)
```

Т.к. это не JSON, а два JSON в одном файле, я открываю их построчно, представляя каждую строку как JSON.

Теперь вопрос, как в таком цикле сохранить модифицированный файл?

Comment: Дык может хранить список словарей, а не тупо словари?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
import json
import dpath.util as du   # pip install dpath


with open(fn) as fin, open(r"c:\temp\result.json", "w") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        d = json.loads(line)
        secret = du.values(d, "/*/Secret")[0]
        if secret in Token:
            du.set(d, "/*/uid", str(username))
            print(json.dumps(d), file=fout)
```